# .or method with 2 different relation tables in supabase js

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I have 2 tables as shown below where user table stores the users profile details and friends table which stores the friendship relation between 2 users where sent column links with user who has sent the request and recieved column links with user who gets the request notification to accept.

```
user {
   id   uuid
   name string
}

friends {
   id         id
   sent       uuid (relation: user.id)
   recieved   uuid (relation: user.id)
   accepted   boolean
}
```

I want to query all the friends table where user's id is present either in sent or recieved field.

I can achieve this using

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('friends')
        .select('*')
        .eq('accepted', true)
        .or(`sent.eq.${user?.id},recieved.eq.${user?.id}`);
```

But the twist is i also want the joint tables of users (sent and request) along with it. Something like

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('friends')
        .select('*, recieved(*), sent(*)')
        .eq('accepted', true)
        .or(`sent.id.eq.${user?.id},recieved.id.eq.${user?.id}`);
```

But the following gives error since both fields come from 2 different foreign tables

Comment: For anything complex like this, it's easier to just use database functions: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions

Comment: Thanks for the reply @dshukertjr!
I exactly thought of this and created a function with a sql query to match my requirements

Comment: The very annoying part about Supabase is that in actual SQL, the above request isn't considered complex.